# Upgrading gitlab to version higher than 13.1.11

Tags: postgresql, gitlab, migration, upgrade

We are upgrading our GITLAB to version higher than 13.1.11, but we are facing DB related issues in proceeding with same.
DB migrations are not getting completed.

ERROR :

```
LINE 5: daterange(start_date, due_date, '[]') WITH &&
^
HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/db/migrate/20200515153633_iteration_date_range_constraint.rb:7:in `up'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

We are not able to proceed since migrations are not getting completed. We have installed btree_gist after that we are getting these errors.

Comment: What is your version you are migrating *from*?

Comment: We are upgrading from 13.1.11 to 13.3 or 13.8 but both versions have same issue with postgre database . We tried on progres 11 and 12 both .

Comment: @VonC FYI Version shared .

Comment: OK. I thought you were trying to upgrade from 11 or 10, in which case I would have recommended an upgrade major version per major version. But no. In this case, it looks like a bug in 13.x.

Comment: It is slightly similar to https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/322619#note_519178270, which suggests to check various table permission. Check if your own case would apply here.

Comment: We have similar underfined funtion issue but its related to datatype not permsission .
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: function daterange(timestamp without time zone, timestamp without time zone, unknown) does not exist
LINE 5: daterange(start_date, due_date, '[]') WITH &&
^
HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/db/migrate/20200515153633_iteration_date_range_constraint.rb:7:in `up'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242848/discussion-between-sapna-and-vonc).